# Getting exception while invoking AZURE SQL trigger function

Tags: sql, function, triggers, azure-sql-database

[image]

I am writing a new azure function based on SQL trigger change notification. Change tracking is enables on AZURE SQL DB and the table but it's giving me some error related to permissions.

When a record in a table changes it will invoke this function app.

Comment: What error, you are getting?

Comment: to see error please click on enter image description here link in my post

Comment: can you please share your function code and the store procedure if you are using any?

Answer (score 0):

Your user (whose credentials are used for your sqlTrigger) needs permissions to create schemas. It will create a schema `az_func` and a few tables in that schema to save its state. In those tables the progress is saved so it knows what changes it still needs to process and keep count of failed attempts.

```sql
GRANT CREATE SCHEMA TO your_user_for_triggers
```

Comment: Thanks it worked after having schema creations rights